# App page being rejected by FB

Tags: facebook

I am trying to create a page for an app on Facebook. But it is being rejected (for the fourth time) for this reason:

> Your icon image should be on a colored or transparent background. Do not use white frames on your icons. Use colored frames to enclose your icon if your icon has white space.

I've followed the guidelines and tried different alternatives. The icon being rejected (in the fourth try) can be found under the following link: http://funryde.com/img/funryde_icon.png. I don't know what it is being missed here. Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your gradient background will be mistaken for plain white by Facebook's system. You will need to add a border around the image (e.g. Photoshop, select all > blending options > inner stroke) OR change your background to a solid colour.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did exactly as you mentionned and as described in the guidelines, and it is still being rejected. The last version that was submitted is under the following link:http://www.funryde.com/img/FB-App-Page-Icons-Logo1.jpg (A border around the image). Also tried transparent background, and still being rejected.